# How to make object output with fixed position and angle?

Tags: plotting

```
RegionPlot3D[
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 0.75}, {y, -1, 0.75}, {z, -1, 1}, 
ImageSize -> 400, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, 
AxesOrigin -> {1, 1, -1}, 
Lighting -> {{"Directional", Gray, ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}, 
ViewPoint -> {-1, 1, -2.7}, ViewAngle -> 35 Degree, 
ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}]
```

I would like this object face to me with position and angle as below:
[image]
But after I compute notebook again, the object position and angle changed to :
[image]
I cannot control the output,even changed to:
[image]

How to solve this porblem?

Comment: Hard to expect anything else if you keep fixed `ViewVertical -> {0, 0, 1}, ViewPoint -> {-1, 1, -2.7}`. Drop it and if you keep rotated output then the new one will inherit view settings.

Comment: Was that the problem?

Comment: I am new to mathematica,need more time to digest your comments,headache!

Comment: Delete `ViewPoint` -> Evaluate plot -> rotate -> evaluate again.

Comment: `ViewPoint gives the position of the view point relative to the center of the three-dimensional box that contains the objects`.This option help to fix the view,why should I delete it?I set wrong ViewPoint?

Comment: If  `ViewPoint` and `ViewVertical` are correct then what is wrong with the output? If they are not correct, why do you want to keep it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many combinations of view point and view angle that will give the figure you want. A fast and easy way to arrive a suitable combination is to use a `Manipulate` expression to shift view point and view angle.

```
Manipulate[
  RegionPlot3D[
    x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 0.75}, {y, -1, 0.75}, {z, -1, 1},
    ImageSize -> 400,
    Lighting -> {{"Directional", Gray, ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}},
    ViewAngle -> angle Degree,
    ViewPoint -> {xV, yV, zV}],
  {{xV, 1}, 0, 5, .1, AppearanceElements -> All}, 
  {{yV, 2}, 0, 5, .1, AppearanceElements -> All},
  {{zV, -2}, -5, 0, .1, AppearanceElements -> All},
  {{angle, 30}, 10, 40, 2, AppearanceElements -> All}]
```

It comes up looking this.

[image: initial]

A few seconds of adjusting the sliders finds an acceptable combination.

[image: adjusted]

That such a combination happens at xV == yV == -zV is a simple exercise in visualization that you should try for yourself.

Now you can write a plot expression that will show your image in the position that you want it to have. I use `Deploy` to prevent the viewer from changing the presented view.

```
Deploy @ 
  RegionPlot3D[
    x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 0.75}, {y, -1, 0.75}, {z, -1, 1},
    ImageSize -> 400,
    Lighting -> {{"Directional", Gray, ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}},
    ViewAngle -> 20 Degree,
    ViewPoint -> {3, 3, -3}]
```

[image: final]

Comment: When I add option `PlotPoints->100`,`Manipulate` has no output.

Comment: @kittygirl. I don't see why you need to add that option. Also, without seeing exactly how you changed my code, I can't really tell what you did wrong. Perhaps, `Manipulate` can't plot fast enough when ask for so many points.

Comment: @kittygirl. Thanks for accepting my answer. But I don't understand why you considered it worth an acceptance but not an up-vote. You are aware, aren't you, that you can do both?

Comment: ,Thanks for your good answer!Abosultely  worth an up-vote!